# Looping through folder and for every file, copy specific cell to a master and save each as a separate workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find a solution to loop the task for a larger volume of files. I was successful for a file with my code but when I added looping to it doesn't get past the first copy.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

I have 100 files in a folder. I want to loop through the folder and work on each file to copy specific cells to a master file "master_file.xlsx" then save the master file with a file name in the different directory as .xlsx.

```
Sub creation2()

Dim myPath As String
Dim Rcd As String
Dim Wb As String
Dim Bs As Workbook


    myPath = "C:\Users\test\"
    Rcd = Dir(myPath & "*") 
    Wb = "x" & Rcd
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While Rcd <> ""
    
    Workbooks.Open Rcd
    Set Bs = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "master_File.xlsx")
    Bs.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\test\new\" & Wb
    Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("A2").Copy
    Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("C3").Copy
    Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("E2").Copy
    Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("E4:I210").Copy
    Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

    Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
       
    Rcd = Dir
    
Loop    
End Sub
```

I have been tweaking my code around as a beginner to the VBA and I have a feeling that some areas are not correct.

Comment: What does "some areas are not correct" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It stops processing with saved master file with a new name and leaves first loop file "Rcd" open. I am wondering if I need to change the "Rcd" or  Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd) part needs to change.

Comment: Save the worksheet object when you do `Workbooks.Open Rcd`. Like `Set TargetBook = Workbooks.Open(Rcd)`. And then when you're searching the `Worksheets` Collection, use an actual name of a worksheet. Like `TargetBook.Worksheets("Name")`.

Comment: Hi Toddleson, thank you for your comment, the worksheet name is same as the work book name (Rcd in this case) :(

Comment: @Sandy Ok perfect! Then I think your problem might be `ActiveWorkbook.Close` is closing the master file inside the loop. I think you meant `Workbooks(Rcd).Close` and then `Workbooks(Wb).Close` after the loop

Comment: Another problem is that you have hardcoded the paste addresses. Which means each set of data will overwrite the last, and when you look at the results, you will only see one set of data. You might want to add a loop counter, and use that with `Offset` to automatically increment the paste address as you go, so each set of data is pasted in a different location.

Comment: When I run this code, Rcd being active at first copy being error with "Subscript out of range (Error 9)"

Comment: You are 'performing' a Dir on a path. Let's say the result is just what you need: `Text.xlsx`. Then you're prepending an `x` making it `xText.xlsx` and, from the same folder, you're opening `master_file.xlsx` and saving it under `xText.xlsx` in the new folder and continue looping in the initial folder. Don't you know what `rcd` is in advance? Also, you may want to skip the `master_file xlsx` in the loop. Where is this code located? Maybe you need to skip the workbook containing this code, too. Please clarify.

Comment: The title cleared some of it. Are these files you're opening CSV files or do they contain a single worksheet? Their worksheets shouldn't have the same name as the workbook. If they do, then explain exactly, using an example, how they are the same, e.g. `Data.xlsx vs Data` or `Data.xlsx vs Data.xlsx`. @Toddleson: Read the title, it isn't quite in sync with the code. I think OP wants to use the master file as a template.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub creation2()

Dim myPath As String
Dim Rcd As String
Dim Wb As String
Dim Bs As Workbook


    myPath = "C:\Users\test\"
    Rcd = Dir(myPath & "*")

    Set Bs = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "master_File.xlsx")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do While Rcd <> ""
    
        Wb = "x" & Rcd
        Bs.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\test\new\" & Wb
        
        Workbooks.Open Rcd
        
        Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("A2").Copy
        Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("C3").Copy
        Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("E2").Copy
        Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Workbooks(Rcd).Worksheets(Rcd).Range("E4:I210").Copy
        Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        Workbooks(Wb).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
           
        Rcd = Dir
    
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
End Sub
```